# configure receive location using wcf-custom sql binding under biz talk server administration console 2010

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

I Created biz talk server project to read multiple row data from stored procedure and send each row to asp.net webservice solution.
i used add generated items( consume adapter service sql binding to select the stored procedure)
I don't know how to configure receive location using wcf-custom sql binding under biz talk server administration console 2010. what i should to write under the following attributes

1. Polled Data available statement
2. Polling statement
3. xml stored procedure root node name
4. xml stored procedure root node name space.

this is the schema generated in the project when i add consume adapter service sql binding

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" ?> 
- <xs:schema xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" xmlns:ns3="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/Procedures/dbo" version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:import schemaLocation=".\DataSetSchema.xsd" namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data" /> 
- <xs:annotation>
- <xs:appinfo>
  <fileNameHint xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/servicemodel/adapters/metadata/xsd">Procedure.dbo</fileNameHint> 
- <b:references>
  <b:reference targetNamespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data" /> 
  </b:references>
  </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
- <xs:element name="getMessages">
- <xs:annotation>
- <xs:documentation>
  <doc:action xmlns:doc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/servicemodel/adapters/metadata/documentation">Procedure/dbo/getMessages</doc:action> 
  </xs:documentation>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:complexType /> 
  </xs:element>
- <xs:element name="getMessagesResponse">
- <xs:annotation>
- <xs:documentation>
  <doc:action xmlns:doc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/servicemodel/adapters/metadata/documentation">Procedure/dbo/getMessages/response</doc:action> 
  </xs:documentation>
  </xs:annotation>
- <xs:complexType>
- <xs:sequence>
  <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="getMessagesResult" nillable="true" type="ns3:ArrayOfDataSet" /> 
  <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="ReturnValue" type="xs:int" /> 
  </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
```

Looking forward for ur assistant
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should to choose wcf-sql adapter, in binding fill rood name and namespace then put the poll statement the the

Comment: if this is the answer check as answered

Answer (score 1):

There are a bunch of really good blog posts out there, along with sample code.

Take a look at:

- http://www.biztalkbill.com/Home/tabid/40/EntryId/95/BizTalk-2010-XML-Polling-with-WCF-SQL-Adapter.aspx
- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8acf96b2-5595-4fed-bb07-9ba523ab7d11/polling-sql-server-2008-r2-database-with-wcfsql-adapter-in-biztalk-2010
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd788532(BTS.70).aspx

Depending on whether you want to invoke your ASP.Net web-service once for all records returned, or once for each record returned (i.e. one call, or multiple calls), you might also want to take a look at this blog post regarding debatching multiple records:

http://seroter.wordpress.com/2010/04/08/debatching-inbound-messages-from-biztalk-wcf-sql-adapter/